# Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code : "Oracle Java SE Language Server not enabled!" error message

Tags: java, vscode-extensions

I installed on VSCode (Version: 1.85.0 - MacOS Ventura) the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code and following the instructions I added to settings.json

```json
  "jdk.jdkhome": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents" (using the provided JDK downloader) and
  "jdk.userdir": "global"
```

then I restarted VSCode and tried the Java: New Project command.
I am getting in the Output the following:

```
Initiating server activation
Request to kill LSP server.
Cannot kill: current process is None
Launching Oracle Java SE Language Server with /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents and userdir /Users/c11886/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/oracle.oracle-java
LSP server launching: 49560
LSP server user directory: /Users/c11886/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/oracle.oracle-java
Cannot find java. Please use the --jdkhome switch.
Cannot find org.netbeans.modules.java.lsp.server in the log!
Request to kill LSP server.
Cannot kill: Requested kill on 49560, current process is None
Oracle Java SE Language Server not enabled!
```

Any idea what I did wrong or missed?